# Not sure about how to turn a contingency table into a histogram or bar graph in R?

Tags: r

The contingency table that need to be changed in to histogram or bar graph
[image: The contingency table that need to be changed in to histogram or bar graph]

I want to plot a histogram or a bar graph from the contingency shown above. Thanks for help。

I just want to learn the process of the conversion, as well as how the result will be look like.

Comment: total number may not required in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Your screenshot looks like its from Excel or a related type of software, so I wonder if you'd be better off just making the bar graph in whatever program you're already using, unless you're also an R user already. R is widely considered to be one of the best way to create attractive and highly customized plots (because it has the `ggplot2` package), so I don't want to turn you away from asking your question here, but if you're not an R user and just need a quick bar graph, I would recommend using what you already have.